# MySQL How to avoid connection lost error when updating a cascading key value?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2013

I am using MySQL shell client from my Apps server connecting to the remote Database server.

I am trying to update the user_id column of my Member table from 'ABC' to 'CDE', I have about 40-50 tables with [FK Member.user_id cascade update] and some of the table is huge, with millions of records of the same user_id ('ABC'). Ps. I knew this db design isn't optimal.

```
UPDATE `member` SET `user_id` = 'CDE' WHERE `user_id` = 'ABC';
```

I am expecting the command above runs for 30-40 minutes but it just failed after 60+- seconds with the following error:

```
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Searched the similar issues from SO but the following suggestions just not working for my case:

```
max_allowed_packet=1073741824
wait_timeout=31536000
interactive_timeout=9999999
net_read_timeout=9999999
net_write_timeout=9999999
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=9999999
```

Note: I did use 'show variables xxx' to verify the above variable after setting them up.

Edit 1: Using MySQL 2nd Gen 5.7 from Google Cloud Platform

Comment: can you show current existing INDEX on the table? by using this command..  SHOW INDEX FROM [tablename]

Comment: If your table dont have index and you have millions of data.  It will work like a turtle.

Comment: @dodzb all of the related tables are having FK to member.user_id, so the user_id from each of the tables are compulsory to index